# Running postgres 9.5 and django in one container for CI (Bamboo)

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, continuous-integration, bamboo

I am trying to configure a CI job on Bamboo for a Django app, the tests to be run rely on a database (postgres 9.5). It seems that a prudent way to go about is it run the whole test in a docker container, as I do not control the agent environment so I cannot install Postgres there.

Most guides I found recommend running postgres and django in two separate containers and using docker-compose to easily manage them. In this scenario each docker image runs just one service, started with CMD. In Bamboo I cannot use docker-compose however, I need to use just one image, so I am trying to get Postgres and Django to run nicely together in one container but with little success so far.

My problem is that I see no easy way to **start Postgres as a service inside docker but NOT as a docker CMD command**, official [postgre image](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/cf9b6cdd64f8a81b1abf9e487886f47e4971abe2/11/Dockerfile) uses an entrypoint.sh approach, also described in the official [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) 
But it is not clear to me how to implement that. I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your only other option is to add in a startup script in your `Dockerfile`, or kick it off as part of your `docker run ...` commands.  We don't generally use the "Docker" tasks, as I find them ... *distasteful* (also why I usually just fall back to running a "Script" task, and directly calling `docker run` in that script task)

Anyway, you'd have to have your Docker container execute a script that would:

1. Start up Postgres (like a `sudo systemctl start postgresql`)
2. Execute your tests.

Your `Dockerfile` will have to install Postgresql and do some minor setup work I imagine (like create relevant users and databases with the proper owner).  Since we're all good citizens, we remember to never run your containers as root, right?

Note - you can always hack around getting two containers to talk to each other without using `docker-compose`.  It's a bit less convenient, but you could do something like:

```
docker run --detach --cidfile=db_cidfile --name ci_db postgresql_image
...
docker run --link ci_db testing_image
```

Make sure that you `EXPOSE` the right ports on the postgresql image to the `testing_image` container.

EDIT:  I'm looking more at my specific case - we just install Postgresql into a base CentOS host rather than use the postgresql default image (using `yum install http://yum.postgresql.org/..../pgdg-centos...rpm` and then just install `postgresql-server` and `postgresql-contrib` packages from there).  There is a `CMD [ "/usr/pgsql-ver/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/pgsql/ver/data"]` in our `Dockerfile`, too.  We don't do anything fancy with the docker container, though.  *NOTE*: we don't use this in production at all, this is strictly for local and CI testing.

Comment: systemctl (or any other init system) is not working in Docker so I am afraid I cannot use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically you would start postgres as a background process in the docker-entrypoint shell script that does otherwise start your django application.

The only trick here is that you need to put a 'trap' command in it so that you can send a shutdown/kill to the background process when your master process stops.

Although I have done that a thousand times, I know that it is a good source for programming errors. In general I do just use my [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) which takes care of running multiple applications as services, just as if the container is a virtual machine hosting multiple applications.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it and let you know if it worked in the coming days.